# Why did this answer get sent to "Late Answers" review queue *after* a moderator edited it?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, moderators, late-answers

On multiple occasions, I have seen a post that was previously edited or commented on by a moderator ending up in a review queue (e.g., "First Questions", "First Answers", "Late Answers", etc.).

Here is one specific example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30293648

Cody edited this post at 2021-11-09 07:45:08Z (as part of reviewing [a pending suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30293491)). A few minutes later, at 2021-11-09 08:04:40Z, the same post was placed into the Late Answers review queue, which is where I saw it.

Now, it stands to reason that if Cody (or any other moderator) would have thought that this post needed to be deleted, he would have done that instead of editing it. Therefore, why would a post be sent to a "First/Late Questions/Answers" review queue *after* being edited by a moderator?

This seems like a bug, or at least an easy way to save the already-overworked reviewers from a pointless effort. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's very clear. The system doesn't trust Cody.

Comment: "*Now, it stands to reason that if Cody (or any other moderator) would have thought that this post needed to be deleted, he would have done that instead of editing it.*" I find the premise here wrong. The *assumption* you seem to go from is that when a moderator acts, it's always the final decision on a post. That's very much *not* the case. Moderators are here to handle exceptional cases. Most stuff that can be done by the community can be left to the community. A moderator is well within their right to do a minor adjustment to a post and leave the community to act on it, if needed.

Comment: @VLAZ When a mod is watching a post, before edit he will read the post and (such as everyone) will see if what he have to do. So, instead of editing it, he will remove because it will not be useful to edit it. That's why -*for me*- it's relevant

Comment: @Elikill58 what you describe is not a requirement of mods. As I said, your premise is faulty. Leads you to a faulty conclusion.

Comment: @Elikill58 Mods are not expected to be SMEs, and so should not be expected to know whether an answer should be deleted by themselves unless there are non-subject issues (like spam, abuse, etc). Likewise, Moderator deletion is irreversible by normal users, so they tend to be further restrained in what they might delete for that reason.

Comment: @TylerH I already flag answer as NNA. The declined reason was "*This isn't an NNA but can be flag for <other flag>*" and the post was well deleted. So the mod think about what he should do. And I think it's logic because else other user with flag it after mod passage for something that will call mod to come back

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Moderators edit for a variety of reasons.  Perhaps they're cleaning up a spam campaign, reverting some sort of vandalism, or performing some sort of semi-automated cleanup.  And they're not subject-matter experts in all areas: Cody's a low-level (in the stack, not in skill!) C++ developer with an iPhone, editing an [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) answer.

Basically, **a moderator making an edit is not a representation that they've fixed all problems with a post**.  Trying to assume their motives is unlikely to be entirely correct, and this seems like few enough total posts that it's probably worth someone keeping it in the queue for someone looking at it *with the specific goal of reviewing the post*.

Comment: This is, of course, all a long way of saying what Bhargav Rao said much more succinctly [above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412964/why-did-this-answer-get-sent-to-late-answers-review-queue-after-a-moderator#comment878640_412964): The system doesn't trust Cody.

Comment: And I don't trust the system!

Comment: I don't understand why an edit don't represent fixed post. Such as in review we are checking if this seems to be good but without checking the content itself (i.e. valuability of answer), it will not really change if you have lot of experience or not, and when it will be edited, it will be pretty, and not deleted for some reason

Comment: Why is Cody’s knowledge of the subject relevant? “Late Answer” reviewers are not supposed to judge the subject matter at all.

Comment: @Holger that doesn't quite seem true. The instructions tell us to *"Watch for hidden gems"*, which we can only identify with subject matter expertise.

Comment: @MarkAmery then, the posts would have to stay in the queue forever, as no-one can be sure to have identified all “hidden gems”.

Comment: @Holger brilliant! In a million years the initial posts that have gone in that queue would have turned into gems due to the immense pressure being under a pile of all of the later entries in the queue. :P

Comment: Item older than 1 week are automatically removed from queue if I well remember. And I agree with Holger

Comment: The way I understand this answer, is that putting an answer in the review queue after editing it is the equivalent of when you, as a code reviewer in programming, comment some nitpicks and then leave the review score on 0 - it basically means "I'm not sufficiently confident in my knowledge on the subject to approve this".

Comment: @EgorHans: Sure, or "I didn't have the time and/or interest to do a proper full review, but I did feel the need to change X".  Not necessarily because of lack of subject-matter knowledge, in the case of mod actions.  They may need to ration their time by only fixing something that needs fixing.  (In a hypothetical case; IDK if that applied here.)

Comment: @VLAZ: And [recycled as firelighters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOFtgCr5X1A&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&t=11m36s)?